# How to view the content of a URI in the console page?

Tags: javascript, json

```
var ourRequeest = new XMLHttpRequest();

ourRequeest.open('GET' 'https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json')

ourRequeest.onload = function() 
{
  console.log(ourRequest.responseText);
};

ourRequest.send();
```

I keep getting this message in my console.

`Uncaught Syntax Error : missing ) after argument list`.

**Question:** Is there something am not doing right?

Answer (score 2):

You have a few problems.

Missing `,` in `.open();` and your variable has two `e`'s  `ourRequeest` also missing `;` at the end of `.open();`

```js
var ourRequeest = new XMLHttpRequest();
ourRequeest.open('GET','https://learnwebcode.github.io/json-example/animals-1.json');
ourRequeest.onload = function(){ 
console.log(ourRequeest.responseText);
};
ourRequeest.send();
```

If you have any questions feel free to ask and I will get back to you as soon as possible.

I hope this helps. Happy coding!